# Near balances dashboard

Tags: nearprotocol, indexer, thegraph

I just want to get dashboard with amount of users balances from 0 to 100N and from 100N to 1000N. I’m sitting on macOS High Sierra and my laptop is old, so I cannot to build whole part of indexer

I’m little bit confused, cause I don’t need to build whole migrations or indexer stuff. Maybe I can do it quietly simple that I think about it?

Answer (score 1):

The indexer for explorer keeps track of a lot of information (more details found [here](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#database-structure)). This information is public, although the access might not be reliable due to high usage volume. If you need reliability, it is recommended to run your own instance of the indexer for explorer or if you don't need all that data, you can run a custom [indexer](https://near-indexers.io).

One of the tables in the [database](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer/blob/master/docs/near-indexer-for-explorer-db.png) is the `account_changes` table which keeps track of all the changes for each account per block. If you wanted to get the latest balance, you could do a reverse order on the `changed_in_block_timestamp` & `index_in_block` and group by `affected_account_id`.